# BroadcastReceiver is not giving any result back

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a question regarding NetworkListener in android.

I have implemented a new class that listen whether there is internet connection available or not (both data and wifi).

The code is as follows:

```
package com.gelliesmedia.thumbqoo.services;
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("THUMBQOO","Network connectivity change");

        if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
            NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                Log.i("THUMBQOO","Network "+ni.getTypeName()+" connected");
            }
        }
        if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.d("THUMBQOO","There's no network connectivity");
        }
    }
}
```

And this how I register it in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<receiver android:name="com.gelliesmedia.thumbqoo.services.NetworkStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I tested it using emulators (genymotion) it does not give me any message back even though I have unplugged my PC LAN cable.

Do I have to use the NetworkStateReceiver class in all Activity classes that I have?

i.e.

```
Public class MainActivity extends MainActivity{
   onCreate(...)
   NetworkStateReceiver x = new NetworkStateReceiver(); <--- like this?
}
```

Do I have to do anything else here? Could anyone point me to a right direction?

Comment: Test it on a real device. The standard emulator doesn't support network state, and it's doubtful Genymotion has done much beyond marketing their "product."

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
public class NetworkReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
                && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        GeneralClass.isHaveInternet = isConnected ? true : false;
        if (isConnected)

            Log.e("NET-------------->", "connecte" + isConnected);

        else
            Log.e("NET------------->", "not connecte" + isConnected);
    }
}
```

to check connection in app.

```
if (GeneralClass.isHaveInternet)

                Log.e("NET-------------->", "connecte" + isConnected);

            else
                Log.e("NET------------->", "not connecte" + isConnected);
```

where GeneralClass.isHaveInternet is `public static boolean isHaveInternet = true;`